# I have a problem with updating function in laravel resource controlling

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel show me this error when I am updating through resource controller

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

I am very new to laravel. Spend more time to overcome this issue.

**This is my Controller.**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $arr['categories'] = Category::all();
        return view('admin.categories.index')->with($arr);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.categories.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $category-> title = $request-> title;
        $category->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.categories.index');
       
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        $arr['category'] = $category;
        return view('admin.categories.edit')->with($arr);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    
    public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $category->title = $request->title;
        $category->update();
        return redirect()->route('admin.categories.index');
       
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**This is my route.**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@test')->name('admin');
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index')->name('test');
Route::resource('/admin/categories', 'Admin\CategoriesController', ['as'=>'admin']);
```

**This is my edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')

<div class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark"> Edit Categories</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> Edit Categories</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.categories.update', $category->id) }}">
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-md-3">Title</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $category->title }}">
                        </div>  
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div> 
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save">
                </div>  
            </div> 
       </form>
    </div>
</section>    

@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rosource controller, update method should be **PUT** or **PATCH**, like :

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PATCH')
</form>
```

So in your code :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.categories.update', $category->id) }}">
    @method('PATCH')
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
                 <label class="col-md-3">Title</label>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                 <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $category->title }}">
                 </div>  
                 <div class="clearfix"> </div> 
         </div> 
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save">
         </div>  
     </div> 
</form>
```

See The Official Documentation of **[Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
Route::post('/admin/categories', 'Admin\CategoriesController@update', ['as'=>'admin'])->name('admin.categories.update');
```